# How to make comparison all column at one in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my code for comparison in one column

`comparison = np.where(cdr['id'] == cdr_final['id'], True, False)`

The result is

`array([ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True])`

How to make this for all column directly, since my dataframe bot have 300+ columns (both of them have similar column name and similar amount of rows)

Comment: `cdr.eq(cdr_final)`?

Comment: It works as expected